# UIPageViewController Page Color?

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I have a UIPageViewController that is working fine.

I am using a texture for the page that is off white. This is all fine, except the back of the page is white which makes it look strange.

I can set the doubleSided property to YES and then use my texture for the other side of the page. But then I loose the front of the page partially showing through to the back.

So, is there anyway to set the page color of the backside with the doubleSided property set to NO?